# Checking the format of a user's input, then splitting it into a dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to figure out how to check an input's format, and then split it into a dictionary (if it's correct). I've been trying to use `isinstance()` which works for the string portion. I realized it wasn't working because the input is a string even when split into a portion with a string, and one with what should be an int. How would I go about checking if the post-split entry is an int even when it's input as a str?

Here is my code so far:

```
##Enter title and column headers.

dataTitle = input('Enter a title for the data:\n')
print('You entered: %s\n' % dataTitle)

col1 = input('Enter the column 1 header:\n')
print('You entered: %s\n' % col1)

col2 = input('Enter the column 2 header:\n')
print('You entered: %s\n' % col2)

##Get data points.

data = {}

while True:
    dataInput = input('Enter a data point (-1 to stop input):\n')
    if dataInput == '-1':
        break
    else:
        x = dataInput.replace(' ', '')
        x = dataInput.split(',')
        if isinstance(x[0], str) & isinstance(x[1], int):
            data.update({x[0], x[1]})
            print(data)
        else:
            print('ERROR')
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the EAFP principle and do

```
try:
    is_int = int(thing)
except Exception as e:
    # cannot be cast to an int, so do other thing
```

Comment: I'd point out that EAFP means to ask forgiveness over permission.

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to `try` casting it to `int` and `except`ing the error for "non-int" inputs. Basically `int('5')` returns `5`, while `int('a')` raises a `ValueError`. You can utilize that...

Answer (score -1):

Use the EAFP (Easier to Ask Forgiveness than Permission) principle:

```
x = dataInput.replace(' ', '')
x = dataInput.split(',')
try:
    data[x[0]] = int(x[1])
except ValueError:
    print('ERROR')
```